# Ruby: Event Machine Tweetstream and Fibers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, eventmachine, fiber

Im have trying to play around with the tweetstream gem to access the twitter's streaming api to fetch tweets and save the tweets in the database.

I have been trying to use eventmachine along with Ruby fibers for the first time to speed up the tweet insertion

I not sure if the way I have used ruby fibers along with event machine is done in the right way. I need help and suggestions telling me if my ruby fibers and event machine implementation is correct.

Just a note that the tweetstream api configuration has been written in an initializer and is working as expected. I just need help someone to look at my implementation and tell me if it can be improved.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'tweetstream' 
require 'eventmachine'
require 'fiber'

class TweetLocator
    #get tweets
    def self.fetch_and_save_tweets
        EventMachine.run do #using eventmachine on tweet insert

            client = TweetStream::Client.new    
            @tweet_fibers = [Fiber.current]

            client.locations(-180, -90, 180, 90) do |tweet|
                @tweet_fibers << Fiber.new do
                    self.save_tweet_to_db(tweet)
                end
                @tweet_fibers.last.resume
            end
        end #end of eventmachine run
    end

    #save tweet
    def self.save_tweet_to_db(tweet)
        if tweet['geo']
            Tweet.create!({
                location: tweet['geo']['coordinates'],
                status: tweet['text'],
                profile_pic_url:  tweet['user']['profile_image_url'],
                user_handle: tweet['user']['screen_name']
            })
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: Ruby fibers are actually semi-coroutines, so your immediate execution without `yield` calls in the `Fiber` body is actually redundant--you could have used a `Proc`.

Comment: I did not get you said? Can you explain terms of code? Prboably a ruby fiddle?

Comment: `@tweet_fibers << Proc.new { self.save_tweet_to_db(tweet) };
@tweet_fibers.last.call`

Comment: In particular, there is no actual "multithreading" or "multifibering" going on with `Fiber`. Under the hood everything is still a single path of execution.

Comment: Thanks.. But if I wanted to use yield How should I have used it?